# Maven SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings [External dependencies]

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I know I can exclude one of the binding which I did in maven so my springboot.jar only contains logback and logback-slf bindings but then there is this external jar that I am referring on spring-boot class path introduces slf4j-log4j binding at runtime and gets confused.

`java -Dprofile=dev -Dloader.path=springboot.jar,/usr/local/hadoop/lib,/usr/local/hbase/lib -jar springboot.jar`

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/runtime/external/classpath/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/build/jar/path/springboot.jar!/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

How do I resolved this when binding conflict is with external dependencies?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow exclude those jars from your classpath. So you shouldn't add the hbase lib dir in general, but enumerate all jarfiles.

In case you are using bash to start your application you can leverage its pattern matching: `/usr/local/hbase/lib/!(slf4j-log4j12-*)`

p.s. this is not a spring-boot question....

Comment: if I do ls -lrt /usr/local/hbase/lib/!(slf4j-log4j12-*) it doesnt work